# Fitting data with given equation having dependent variable on both sides of equation in Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am  new at coding and stil in the learning stage. My objective is to find parameters (i.e. J0, Rs, A, Rsh) from the equation below,

```
J= -J0*[exp{q((V+Rs*J)/A*k*T)}-1]-(V-Rs*J)/Rsh
```

where `q = 1.60e-19`, `k = 2.208e-42`, and `T = 298.0`.

I have been trying to fit this using curve_fit fucntion of scipy.optimize but it does not accept both independent and dependent variables in it. I tried to find other possible solutions on google but pretty much lost until now. Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

    
V = np.array([-0.5 , -0.48, -0.46, -0.44, -0.42, -0.4 , -0.38, -0.36, -0.34,
   -0.32, -0.3 , -0.28, -0.26, -0.24, -0.22, -0.2 , -0.18, -0.16,
   -0.14, -0.12, -0.1 , -0.08, -0.06, -0.04, -0.02,  0.  ,  0.02,
    0.04,  0.06,  0.08,  0.1 ,  0.12,  0.14,  0.16,  0.18,  0.2 ,
    0.22,  0.24,  0.26,  0.28,  0.3 ,  0.32,  0.34,  0.36,  0.38,
    0.4 ,  0.42,  0.44,  0.46,  0.48,  0.5 ,  0.52,  0.54,  0.56,
    0.58,  0.6 ,  0.62,  0.64,  0.66,  0.68,  0.7 ,  0.72,  0.74,
    0.76,  0.78,  0.8 ,  0.82,  0.84,  0.86,  0.88,  0.9 ,  0.92,
    0.94,  0.96,  0.98,  1.])
J = np.array([-4.516e-04, -4.282e-04, -4.044e-04, -3.824e-04, -3.598e-04,
   -3.389e-04, -3.173e-04, -2.973e-04, -2.770e-04, -2.577e-04,
   -2.388e-04, -2.202e-04, -2.028e-04, -1.849e-04, -1.684e-04,
   -1.515e-04, -1.358e-04, -1.198e-04, -1.047e-04, -8.970e-05,
   -7.477e-05, -6.028e-05, -4.567e-05, -3.078e-05, -1.582e-05,
    1.346e-08,  1.658e-05,  3.469e-05,  5.357e-05,  7.427e-05,
    9.664e-05,  1.207e-04,  1.459e-04,  1.737e-04,  2.031e-04,
    2.342e-04,  2.679e-04,  3.022e-04,  3.406e-04,  3.788e-04,
    4.220e-04,  4.662e-04,  5.162e-04,  5.714e-04,  6.347e-04,
    7.134e-04,  8.095e-04,  9.477e-04,  1.132e-03,  1.415e-03,
    1.837e-03,  2.524e-03,  3.517e-03,  5.171e-03,  7.452e-03,
    1.091e-02,  1.564e-02,  2.241e-02,  3.047e-02,  4.127e-02,
    5.331e-02,  6.810e-02,  8.428e-02,  1.026e-01,  1.228e-01,
    1.444e-01,  1.675e-01,  1.926e-01,  2.179e-01,  2.460e-01,
    2.732e-01,  3.037e-01,  3.097e-01,  3.098e-01,  3.097e-01,
    3.097e-01])

q = 1.60e-19
k = 2.208e-42
T = 298.0


def func (V, J, J0, Rs, A, Rsh):    #V and J are both variables
    return -J0*(np.exp(q*(V+Rs*J)/A*k*T)-1) - (V-Rs*J)/Rsh

P0 = [1.0e-3, 1.0, 1.0, 1000.0]

c, cov = curve_fit(func, V, J, P0)

print('fitting parameters')             #show optimal parameters
print(c)
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. You are right that `curve_fit` is not the right tool here. You have something like y = f( y, a ) or y - f( y, a ) = 0. So "simply" finding the minimum of the latter with respect to `a` would be an answer. One can put some thought, however, in what  "minimizing" actually means here. Probably analog to least squares the sum of squares at your measurement points.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, you might use `curve_fit` after all. You define g( y, a ) = y - f( y, a ) and then minimize `curve_fit( g, y, z ), where `z = [ 0, 0, ... ]`

Comment: dear Mikuszefski, Thanks! I already tried to run this function the way you have suggested but always there is some error. Could you please give detail how to write this particular function in curve_fit?

Comment: Is `k` the Boltzmann constant? In which units is that?

Comment: Thank a lot for writing code for my problem. Yes, k is Boltzmann constant mulitplied which is multiplied with 1.60e-19. In this case, q will be omiited from the numerator. I am still trying to understand the code. By the way, why did you use "Jl" instead of "Rsh" as it is one of the fitting parameters? I am confused.

Comment: Hi, concerning the `J1` it was basically easier to program and technically it dos not make a difference. You have one additional free parameter, such that this part is somewhat independent of the rest. In such a case you can directly fit it as one parameter. If later you say it is connected to other parameters via this or that relation, you can just use standard error propagation to get the according parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a try with some generic data, which is produced self consistently.
Further explanation are as comments in the code:

```
import numpy as np
from warnings import warn
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

q = 1.60e-19 # electron charge in As
k = 1.38e-23 # in J/K
T = 298.0 #room temperature in K
qikT = q/k/T

# ~print qikT

# J= -J0*[exp{q((V+RsJ)/A kT)}-1]-(V-RsJ)/Rsh
# as Rsh is an independent variable we can set the constant term as variable Jl

def f( J, J0, Jl, V, Rs, n ):
    exponent = qikT * ( (V + Rs * J ) / n )
    out = np.exp( exponent )
    out = -J0 * out
    out += Jl
    return out


def find_selfconsistent( J0, Jl, V, Rs, n ):
    test = True
    cnt = 0
    jj = -1
    while test:
        jjj = f( jj, J0, Jl, V, Rs, n )
        # ~print jjj
        cnt += 1
        if cnt > 150 or np.fabs( ( jjj - jj ) / jj ) < 1e-6 : # 0.1% change
            if cnt > 150:
                warn("not converged", UserWarning )
            test = False
        else:
            jj = jjj
    return jjj

"""
I don't know if these values make sense, but it converges
"""
vl = np.linspace( -.5, 1, 25 )
jl = np.fromiter( ( find_selfconsistent( 1e-2, 1.2e-4, v, 300.6, 90.0 ) for v in vl ), np.float )

# ~print jl
"""
now curve_fit wants a function that it calls as f( x, params ) 
and it optimizes params so
( y - f( x, params )^2 is minimum
We have, hence, to write a wrapper.
"""

def wrapper( jlist, J0, Jl, Rs, n ):
    """
        jl will be passed as list 
        and we know that vl is of the same shape
    """
    out = list()
    if not isinstance( jlist, np.ndarray ):
        raise( TypeError, "unexpected" )
    for j, v in zip( jlist, vl): # vl is global!
        out.append( j - f( j, J0, Jl, v, Rs, n ) )
    return np.array( out )

# test
print wrapper( jl, 1e-2, 1.2e-4, 300.6, 90.0 ) ## is basically zero

sol, _ = curve_fit( wrapper, jl, np.zeros( len( jl ) ), p0 = [ 1e-2, 1.2e-4, 300.6, 90.0 ])
print sol
## works
## very likely one needs good starting values in p0
```