# How to obtain the parameters by fit the MOSFET I-V_DS data in the case of series resistances are consider by PYTHON

Tags: python, curve-fitting

How to obtain the parameters by fit the MOSFET I-V_DS data in the case of series resistances are consider, the fitting equation likes as " I = M*( ( V_GS-I*R- V_TH-(V_DS-2*I*R)/2)*(V_DS-2*I*R)- 2/3*( (V_DS-2*I*R)**(3/2)) ) ", note the current variabel 'I' appears in both side of equation. The 'M and R' need to be obtained via fitting.

I have try the method ref. 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63129049/fitting-data-with-given-equation-having-dependent-variable-on-both-sides-of-equa', but can not get it done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.